# css and scss not loaded on some components - reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

After updating our project to a new version of the react (`15.6` to `16.2`), 70% of the components of React ceased loading the css.

To put it bluntly, css works only in the header and footer.
Moreover, the importation in these components is performed by an identical method.

webpack:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const config = require('../config');
const write = require('./write');
const defaultConfig = require('./default.config');

module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'app'),
                            // path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules/react-html-converter'),
                            // path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules/react-attr-converter'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'utils'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'config')
            ]
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', `css?module&localIdentName=${config.get('classnames:production')}&-minimize!postcss`)
        }, {
            test: /\.sss$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', `css?module&localIdentName=${config.get('classnames:production')}&-minimize!postcss?parser=sugarss`)
        }]
    }
```

Component in which css doesn't load

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PropTypes as T} from 'prop-types';
import cx from 'classnames';
import Link from 'react-router/lib/Link';
import styles from './index.css';

class Post extends Component {

    render(): any {
        return (
                <Link to={`/news/`} className={styles.container}>
                    <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
                </Link>
            </article>
        );
    }
}

export default Post;
```

I am almost certain that I gave too little information to fully understand the situation. Perhaps you can tell me what I should pay attention to and how to deal with such problems in general, since there are no errors at app run.

Thanks for any of your advice!

Comment: is it possible to share giturl to your project?

Comment: what is `test: /\.sss$/,` ? it has to be `test: /\.scss$/,`

Comment: I do not know why it is written that way, but it works, honestly. 

Unfortunately, I can't give the repository, but if you need any other information to understand the problem, I will gladly provide it.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: is it possible to post your complete `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` ?

Comment: sure! here is `package.json` : https://jsonblob.com/e425eb0d-641d-11e9-b398-fd61c5621694 , and `production.config.js` from wepback folder: https://jsfiddle.net/g865ybtj/ . thank you very much :)

Comment: in your title you've mentioned `css and scss`. i don't see any `sass` loaders in your `package.json`. are you getting any errors during build?

Comment: no, but the project has been working with the current code for 3 years already. moreover, the header and footer, despite the fact that they use `sss` files, are working properly. however, they are located in different directories of the `app` folder, but I did not find any special differences inside. I can send 2 components together with `sss`, one of which works, and the second does not. maybe it can help?

Comment: I forgot to say, we also have components with a pure `css`, but the styles in them are not loaded either

Comment: you can send those 2 components. there are many online editors for react like https://stackblitz.com . you can also make of use it to share code with others, use whatever is convenient for you.

Comment: @divine I spent enough time to try to figure it out on my own and found out the following. components have almost identical code, including a bunch of other components, publishing them will not help to understand the nature of the problem. Currently, about 15 style files are generated in HTML, and they are present in the markup. The rest do not get there. Moreover, I did not observe these tags in the markup before (most likely, one style file was created, not several). Style files are generated from both `css` and `sss` files. Tell me, please, maybe the problem is somehow related to this?

Comment: it would be helpful to debug if your share your code somehow. I'm not able to figure out the problem but I understand what you're saying